# check if user scrolled to a certain percentage of screen

Tags: jquery, css

At the moment, I have the following...

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > 1150)
```

So if the user scrolls past 1150px this condition is called. Is there a way to change my if condition so that if the user scrolls to 20% of the screen, rather than a given pixel number, than the if condition will be called.

The reason I ask is because this if condition does not take into consideration the heights of different screens. When I test this on different screen sizes I get different results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually already using everything you need to do that. I would suggest using the native `window` property `innerHeight` instead of `$(window).height`though.

What you want to do is specify a maximum height depending on your current `innerHeight` before you do the check:

```
var maxHeight = window.innerHeight * 0.2;
if( $(window).scrollTop() > maxHeight ) {
   // do what you want to do
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Note that whole page height is document.height not window.height

```
if (($(window).scrollTop()/$(document).height()) > 0.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($(window).height()*20)/100)
```

Comment: Please add some surrounding explanation so that the person who asked the question understands what this does.